# Loading Data into Snowflake table from a CSV file

Tags: excel, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, data-analysis, data-cleaning

I've been trying to add data from a csv file into snowflake database. I use the load data GUI option to upload the data. The problem is that since it is a **CSV file** '**,**' is the delimiter and the data inside one of the columns has **,** in it so it is considering it as a delimiter and splitting the columns. Can you suggest a way to upload the data without the above case happening?
Thanks.

Comment: If the "file" is CSV and the delimiter is comma, and those columns are not escaped with something like single quotes or double quotes, it's not really a CSV file. It's just text. Now there are libraries that help, guess, the "true" comma's from embedded comma's, But this is the realm of fix the code emitting the data.

Comment: Yes, my bad the file is separated by double quotes and setting field enclosed by as double quotes is solving the problem. Thanks